# Modify value on indexed field in DynamoDB

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have a **Users** table with an index on the `username` field. This makes it possible for me to search for users by username.

When I update an object's `username` field, fx from "Alice" to "Bob", then no items are returned to me when I subsequently call:

```
// Fetch the user with username Bob
const params = {
  TableName: 'Users',
  IndexName: 'username-index',
  KeyConditionExpression: 'username = :value',
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':value': 'Bob'
  }
}

const result = await dynamo.query(params).promise()
```

It seems to me that "Bob" is not added to the index. I am doing the update in a wrong way or is there a way for me to update the index?

******************************* UPDATE *******************************

This is code used to update the username:

```
const params = {
  TableName: 'Users',
  Key: { _id: USER_ID },
  UpdateExpression: 'SET username = :value',
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':value': username
  }
}
const result = await dynamo.update(params).promise()
```

I have looked in the AWS Console and verified that the username has in fact been changed. Also, when I look under **Indexes** I can see that the **Item count** for the `username-index` is 18, while the number of users is 19.

Comment: Which index you are using local or global secondary index? Note that index update is async but it should happen fairly quickly. How long did you wait for querying on index after the update.

Comment: I am using GSI - I have tried up to 15 minutes after; still not working

Comment: Did you check the entry directly though AWS console?

Comment: Can you add your update query too, I guess that might be failing altogether

Comment: Can you please insert a new item in the table and see whether it gets reflected in GSI? I am just thinking whether there is any unlikely failure scenario happening on data sync between table and GSI. Also, please note that the data sync doesn't happen synchronously. However, in normal condition, it should be completed in a fraction of seconds.

Comment: I have just added a new item, and it is reflected in the index. I have tried to wait like 30 seconds after the UPDATE with the same result